# Trying to load another html page into a div using jQuery. I looked at other posts but mine still isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, load

Please have a look. EDIT: here is a link to a fiddle for the entire code: http://jsfiddle.net/e77aqubx/

This is a section of the jQuery (everything above it seems to be working fine). I am trying to get portfolio.html to show up in the #portfolio div (which is not visible until you click the link for it). The portfolio.html is in the same folder in the directory so I don't think I have to worry about the link.

```
    $("#portfolio_link").click(function(){
    $(".header").hide();
    $("#about").hide();
    $("#portfolio").show();
    $("#portfolio").load("portfolio.html");

});
```

I have a div set up for it in the html as

```
<div id="portfolio">ooh blah dee</div>
```

In the jQuery I also tried:

```
$("#portfolio").show(function(){
    $("#portfolio").load("portfolio.html");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using IFrames? If I understand your issue correctly you can simply change the display of the element on action using something like `.toggle()`

example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lsvmjqed/)

Edit:
As far as the current code, i would really need to see some more info as your code appears, at a simple form anyway, correct. Can you provide your file structure, or the results from the networking tab in dev tools when you run the event? Or even give this a shot on your `.load()`:

```
$( "#portfolio" ).load( "portfolio.html", function() {
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

However it's important to remember that `.load()` is an ajax call so everytime you run your display method you're rendering a view via ajax instead of that one time iframe.

Comment: Thanks--might try it but would also like to work out the code I currently have because it seems like it should be working. I want to know what I'm doing wrong with the current code so I know for next time.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, the problem might be that the #portfolio_link element is created in the DOM after you attempt to attach the event listener.  This could be solved by attaching the event listener to the 'body' tag and filtering down to any click events on children matching the '#portfolio_link' DOM selector.

Try this:

```
$('body').on('click', '#portfolio_link', function(){
    $('.header').hide();
    $('#about').hide();
    $('#portfolio').show();
    $('#portfolio').load('portfolio.html');
});
```

Comment: Interesting idea. I tried the code but it still didn't work :( However, maybe you're right about the order of things happening.

Comment: I also tried writing the load line at the top before the lines of click events. I added an alert message just to see if i goes through and the alert message pops up but still no webpage in the specified div.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery works in chain. 
Also try first to load and then hide.
Can you use Firebug or Chrome devoper tools to see 
what is happening with DOM?